# Flutter: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both error only when 'flutter run'

Tags: flutter

```
   objc[88755]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3deb0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a344f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    objc[88755]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is
    implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3df00) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a34548). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    objc[88755]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in
    both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3df50) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a34598). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    objc[88755]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3dfa0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a345e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    objc[88755]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3dff0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a34638). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    objc[88755]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb3e040) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versi
    ons/A/MobileDevice (0x103a34688). One of the two will be used. Which one is
    undefined.
    2022-05-13 00:59:55.256 xcodebuild[88755:414710] Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-13 00:59:55.256 xcodebuild[88755:414710] Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

What have I done

- flutter clean
- removing DerivedData folder
- xcode command tool select

flutter doctor comes without any problem. However, running this flutter project on XCode works fine.

I am just curious where the error is coming from? Since, I can't run the app by 'flutter run', I can't do any quick refresh.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.

Comment: Me too. Popped up in CodeMagic (CI/CD) today. Flutter 3 related?

Comment: Tried to look for the solution but nothing has been worked. Crazy lol. I might just create a new project at this point.

Comment: Me too. Any solutions?

Comment: Also ran into this today with CodeMagic. Android builds flutter perfectly but iOS just keeps throwing this error no matter what target I select.

Answer (score 1):

**try the following commands**

```
cd ios/
      pod cache clean --all
      pod deintegrate --verbose
      pod setup --verbose
      pod install --verbose
```

Comment: It did not change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem. It was not xcode or Android studio's problem but Pubspec.yaml's. Try checking for any misspellings or typos in your pubspec.yaml. Even though there was a typo on pubspec.yaml, when i did pub get, it was fine, but when I rebuilt, it was crushed. It did not show the problem on pubspec.yaml while I was running on the IOS simulator, but when i checked the project on Chrome, it showed the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svol5.jpg)